# Shark crashes on processor bandwidth trace

Tags: performance, macos, shark

Shark started crashing on me when I use the "Processor Bandwidth (Core 2)" mode of analysis. It collects the samples, spends the time to analyze them, and crashes with a bus error about when the window should come up.

First I thought it might be because I've been running on low memory. I installed the latest system updates, rebooted, tried again. No difference. Installed latest XCode, no difference. Used CHUD Remover, reinstalled Shark, rebooted, no difference. Tried building with symbols and without.

All the other analyses work. I don't have any third-party KEXTs and never had problems with this before.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there another forum where I can ask this kind of thing? (Apple's dev forums require a $500/yr support package!) Is there a verbose mode for Shark, perhaps via command-line option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the apple [perfoptimization-dev](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/perfoptimization-dev) mailing list.

Even if this turns out to be an easily solved issue, please [file a bug](http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).  You need to have a developer account, but a free account is fine.

Comment: Note that there is often a newer version of Shark available in the CHUD Tools package than the version in the Xcode package. I've no idea if this is the case currently (I'm away from my development machine) but it might be worth checking.